# Embedded C. Make a structure extern vs passing it by reference to another source

Tags: c, embedded, structure

Not particularly experienced in C, chance made be responsible for a small microcontroller project.

So, i have a structure which resides on a file1.c. Its used by several functions in that file. It was defined as static volatile Structure struct right now.

The struct is declared static because i read on a book called "embedded system development coding reference guide" that "variables accessed by several functions defined in the same file shall be declared with static in the file scope". Well, its used by several functions, and i want it file based so i thought it matches that description. Volatile because it holds some AD reads from some ports.

I also have a file2.c which needs to access values of the same structure.

From my understanding my options are the following

1. on file1.h define that structure as extern and access 
         #include file1.h on file2.c and access it.
         From my undestanding though,this will make the structure visible to 
         the whole file2.c even though only 1 function there is going to need 
         it
2. keep the structure as is, and make a function in file.2 which accepts 
         the structure by reference function(Structure *struct), make that 
         function accessible from file1.c and just pass the value by ref 
         function(&struct)

Which one is the best approach? I know that both of them work, but is there a specific reason why i should use one and not the other etc?

I want to clarify that the typedef { variables } Structure, is in another header file which is included on both file1.c and file and file2.c, so there is no question about the files recognizing the structure. I am asking which is the best way to access that structure from where is needed.

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing _why_ the structure is static volatile. Is it hardware registers, DMA buffer, what? I would assume it is declared as such for a reason.

Comment: the header file for `file1` needs to define (not declare) the structure.  The modifier `static` needs to be removed. The file `file1.h` needs to be included in file: `file2.c`

Comment: Its declared static because i read on a book called "embedded system development coding reference guide" that "variables accessed by several functions defined in the same file shall be declared with static in the file scope". Well, its used by several functions, and i want it file based so i thought it matches that description. Volatile because it holds some AD reads from some ports

Comment: Maybe it is better to not make the whole `struct` `volatile`, just the members which should be `volatile`? Do you update the values in a interrupt or other thread? If not, you do not need `volatile`.

Comment: There is a third, better option - access/method functions in file.2 that access the structure.  That provides better safety and encapsulation.  You can then enforce read-only semantics, and data validation, and by more easily apply access breakpoints in debugging.  Of your options 1 and 2, 2 would be preferable in most cases.  You should read https://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals perhaps.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i needed. If you want please replay as a new thread so i can select it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the struct definition to an header file otherwise file2.c won’t recognize the struct even you pass it by reference . A reference or a pointer still need a class/struct definition to be compiled...

Comment: yes i know. the typedef { variables } Structure, is in another header file which is included on both file1.c and file and file2.c

Comment: You did not mention that .. by the way as a general personal rule , if you define a struct or an object inside I.e file1.c , all the functions that access this structure should reside only in file1.c that should also expose helper methods or functions that does jobs working on the struct but without exposing it’s existance to other files .. consider it as an isolation ..

Comment: Sorry, this is pretty much the first time that i am asking here something. I added that clarification on the original question. Thanks for that rule, i will try to follow it. So, i need to try to avoid accessing it from the second file in the first place.

Comment: Well off course there are circumstances where you cannot obey to this but consider the files as c++ classes In terms of isolation as much as possible .. in your example your struct has volatile members so it refer to gpios or whatever else so I would call the file io.c and expose functions like setgpio(int n, int value) where you do not need to reference the struct holding all the low level stuff ...

Comment: The question was which of the two options is "better" - this does not address the question.  It is just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification, the `struct` should probably not be `volatile` qualified. Just because the actual ADC hardware registers are `volatile`, it doesn't mean that the data read from them has to be. Except if you fill the struct from an ISR or from DMA, but that doesn't sem to be the case(?).

The proper design is then to place the `typedef` of the struct in the header file and the variable definition in the .c file. Then provide access to the variable through getter/setter functions. However, consider if other code really need to access the struct as is, or if they just need a few values from it. Overall, use private encapsulation and stay away from `extern`.

Comment: thank you. Honestly, the project is still a mess. when i got it it had 20000 lines of code on a single file, everything volatile and global. The rest i can handle, but for volatile i have read a few horror stories here and there and i just left them like this for now, even though yes, i guess 90% of them dont need the prefix. Yes i know that i lose some optimization, but cpu usage is still not very tight.